# Databricks Notebook 8.3 (Apache Spark 3.1.1, Scala 2.12) | pyspark | Parquet write exception | Multiple failures in stage materialization

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, feature-engineering, aws-databricks

This is a Production code running fine until last week. Then, this parquet write error showed up and never getting resolved.

While writing to AWS S3 in parquet format, I tried several dataframe.repartitions(300) - 300, 500, 2400, 6000. But no luck. The code by itself runs fine, but some times gives count error if I add a count() on a dataframe. (intermittently).
So I removed all the count()s in the code to run the code without errors. Now, It fails while writing to the AWS s3 location.

The code is running on Databricks notebook - Databricks Runtime Version
8.3 (includes Apache Spark 3.1.1, Scala 2.12). The code is written in pyspark(python 3.8). The code runs on AWS r5.8xlarge instances.
I am stuck with this, any help is very much appreciated.

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2026517708936858> in <module>
      3 
      4 #save data_agg for next step
----> 5 dataframe.repartition(6000).write.parquet(s3://path_to_write, mode='overwrite')

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in parquet(self, path, mode, partitionBy, compression)
   1275             self.partitionBy(partitionBy)
   1276         self._set_opts(compression=compression)
-> 1277         self._jwrite.parquet(path)
   1278 
   1279     def text(self, path, compression=None, lineSep=None):

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115     def deco(*a, **kw):
    116         try:
--> 117             return f(*a, **kw)
    118         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    119             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1773.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:1079)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:1079)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:468)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:303)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:964)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Multiple failures in stage materialization.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.cleanUpAndThrowException(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:838)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$getFinalPhysicalPlan$1(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.getFinalPhysicalPlan(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.doExecute(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:378)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:233)
    ... 34 more
    Suppressed: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ShuffleMapStage 46 (parquet at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Connecting to /100.64.19.5:4048 failed in the last 4750 ms, fail this connection directly
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.$anonfun$next$1(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:686)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:577)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.next(CompletionIterator.scala:29)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:484)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:490)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage14.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage14.sort_addToSorter_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage14.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:757)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RowIteratorFromScala.advanceNext(RowIterator.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeFullOuterJoinScanner.advancedLeft(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:1088)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeFullOuterJoinScanner.<init>(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:1078)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinExec.$anonfun$doExecute$1(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:119)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:812)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1643)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:815)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:671)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connecting to /100.64.19.5:4048 failed in the last 4750 ms, fail this connection directly
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:214)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalBlockStoreClient.lambda$fetchBlocks$0(ExternalBlockStoreClient.java:101)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:153)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.lambda$initiateRetry$0(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:181)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2765)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2712)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2706)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2706)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:2263)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2970)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2914)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2902)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    Suppressed: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ShuffleMapStage 46 (parquet at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Connecting to /100.64.19.5:4048 failed in the last 4750 ms, fail this connection directly   at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:771)    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.$anonfun$next$1(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:686)  at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)     at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:577)     at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:70)  at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.next(CompletionIterator.scala:29)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:484)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:490)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)   at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage14.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage14.sort_addToSorter_0$(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage14.processNext(Unknown Source)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:757)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RowIteratorFromScala.advanceNext(RowIterator.scala:83)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeFullOuterJoinScanner.advancedLeft(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:1088)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeFullOuterJoinScanner.<init>(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:1078)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinExec.$anonfun$doExecute$1(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:222)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:125)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)     at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:150)    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:119)   at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:91)   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:812)    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1643)    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:815)     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)   at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)     at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:671)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connecting to /100.64.19.5:4048 failed in the last 4750 ms, fail this connection directly  at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:214)     at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalBlockStoreClient.lambda$fetchBlocks$0(ExternalBlockStoreClient.java:101)    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:153)     at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.lambda$initiateRetry$0(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:181)  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)  at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)    ... 1 more ]
```

Comment: `...Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connecting to /100.64.19.5:4048 failed ...` sounds like a conectivity issue.

Comment: Yes, usually I have encountered this error when some connection issues happen.

Comment: As a side note, `.count()` is an action and processing actually begins, hence it was failing there. Removing it means the final write will be the first action and thus it fails here. Also, you should not use counts if they are not needed, usually you can get them from the Spark UI.

Comment: You can try increasing `spark.network.timeout` (default is 120s). And also try increasing `spark.executor.memory` if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the following error due to stage materialization.

```
Connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an 
instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP 
connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not 
blocked by a firewall.
```

Stage materialization may happen due to connection issues at intermediate stages where a connection required to be established may have broken.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps: Are you using `.checkpoint` or `.local_checkpoint`? I was facing a similar issue (*stage materialization*) and found it helpful:

> If this problem persists, you may consider using `rdd.checkpoint()` instead, which is slower than local checkpointing but more fault-tolerant.